# Calling JasperServer Dashboard From JSP

Tags: jsp, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a dashboard item in my JasperServer that I want to call programatically from my JSP. I already knew how to call a report, but for dashboards I don't know how to do it. How do we call the dashboard from a JSP page? And how can I pass the parameters for the report inside the dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no web services API to call dashboards like there is for reports. This will surely be added someday... but for now you can only call a dashboard with an HTTP call.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you should be able to do this by using the "hidden_" prefix on any parameter value:

```
http://yourserver.com:8080/jasperserver-pro/flow.html?_flowId=dashboardRuntimeFlow&dashboardResource=%2Fpublic%2Fdashboard%2F&j_username=myusername%7Cmyorganisation&j_password=mypassword&hidden_mymessageparamname=HelloWorld&decorate=no&viewAsDashboardFrame=true
```

You can ommit the last two parameters in case you want to display all the decoration and toolbars from the Jasper Server.

So in the JSP you can have a form with all the parameters as hidden inputs, but with a name prefixed by "hidden_".

Hope it still could help someone

Comment: You could also use it for embedding an iFrame into your application. Make sure you have the corresponding input controls with the same name as the parameters (visible or not)